# How to force a WebView to show FB Authorization Dialogs? Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, webview

Normally when u click on a "sign up with Facebook" button on a web browser a new tab will popup. But when you try to do the same thing on a `WebView` it doesn't do anything it stays on the same website. How can i force a `WebView` to show the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `-webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:` in your delegate. You'll likely also need to implement at least some of the WebUIDelegate protocol methods, if you haven't already.

Ref: [WebPolicyDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003835), [WebUIDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003838)

Comment: which WebUIDelegate methods i need to use to show the FB Authorization Dialog on the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're probably looking for. Put it inside your AppDelegate.m, then all external links will open in the default browser:

```
// Habilita links externos abrirem no navegador padrão
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    // HACK: This is all a hack to get around a bug/misfeature in Tiger's WebKit
    // (should be fixed in Leopard). On Javascript window.open, Tiger sends a null
    // request here, then sends a loadRequest: to the new WebView, which will
    // include a decidePolicyForNavigation (which is where we'll open our
    // external window). In Leopard, we should be getting the request here from
    // the start, and we should just be able to create a new window.

    WebView *newWebView = [[WebView alloc] init];
    //[newWebView setUIDelegate:self];
    [newWebView setPolicyDelegate:self];

    return newWebView;
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener {
    if( [sender isEqual:myWebView] ) {
        [listener use];
    }
    else {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey]];
        [listener ignore];
        //[sender release];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey]];
    [listener ignore];
}
// -
```

(sim, eu sou br!)